# Can i use SATA hard drives with IBM servers

Tags: hard-drive, webserver, hardware-rec, sas, rack

I am planning to but `IBM X 3850 M2 server`

http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5073028

One friend told me that i can only use `SAS drives` and i can't use `SATA Hard drives` on it.

I want to know is it true

Also it has 2 PSU. Can i just use one or i have to use both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the red book it looks as if SATA 2 is supported only with the ServeRAID-MR10M card

> http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4362.pdf
>   Pages 29-31